# maven child modules not inheriting repository tags

Tags: java, maven

I've declared release and snapshot repositories in the parent POM so as to make them available to all child modules

Here's the parent repository tag

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>foo-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexusrm.cloud.bar.com/repository/foo-releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>foo-milestones</id>
        <url>https://nexusrm.cloud.bar.com/repository/foo-milestones/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <!-- bleeding edge -->
        <id>foo-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://nexusrm.cloud.bar.com/repository/foo-snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

We also have a mirror but that is mapped to `central` `spring-milestones` and `spring-releases` only

```
<mirrors> 
    <mirror>
    <id>bar-maven-mirror</id>
    <name>bar Hosted Maven Mirror</name>
    <url>https://nexusrm.cloud.bar.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>!foo-snapshots,!foo-releases,!foo-milestones,!lp-snapshots,!lp-releases,*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

***The parent POM is built and published to the `foo-snapshots` repository.***

Problem I'm facing is that the build in my child module fails with the following error unless I copy the `<repositories>` tag in it. Since I've already added that tag to the Parent POM and expect to be inherited; doing this step seems redundant, however, that's when the build succeeds.

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.bar.cloud:foo-kafka-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/anadimisra/code/bar/foo/libraries/foo-kafka-client/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.bar.cloud:foo-kafka-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.bar.cloud:foo:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have also declared the parent in `kafka-client`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bar.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

**NOTE**: these are all spring boot microservices, which get built in Serverless Pods on commit, hence parent and child modules are all in separate repositories and ***thereby adding profiles or building from parent is not the solution I'm looking for as it is not feasible in my case***.

Comment: Multi module projects should always be built from the parent project. This way, the parent POM is built first, and then the modules.  Additionally, one should note that it is much better to define repositories and mirrors in the  `settings.xml` than in the POMs.

Comment: But that idea would not go well if we’re building Microservices as it is here; hence a parent file to ensure library versions are common across all Microservices; or else it’ll quickly get out of hand.

Comment: What is "that idea"? You can have a separate parent POM (like a company parent POM), but if you have a multi-module project, it is better to build from the parent POM. You still can build only some of the modules if you which (with flags like `-pl` and `-am`).

Comment: Why should I live with such a monolithic way of running the whole nine yards, is beyond my comprehension. Anyway, my question is simple, why are repository tags not inherited? Any other discussion are digressions which I’m not interested indulging at the moment.

Comment: The error says your parent POM is not found because you did not build it before the module. This is what I am talking about.

Comment: And furthermore you would not have the problem in the first place if you moved your repository definitions to the `settings.xml`.

Comment: Parent POM is built and published to the snapshots repository it does not get resolved until I replicate the repository tag to child module; my bad. I'll elaborate the question.

Comment: @JFabianMeier tried adding repos to `settings.xml` gives this error `Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen ...</servers>\r\n    <repositories>... @21:19)  @ /Users/anadimisra/code/foo/settings.xml, line 21, column 19`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a 'maven install' on your parent first? If it is not installed in your local maven repository, other libraries won't find it.

Also why use another versioning scheme for your parent (e.g 1.0-SNAPSHOT) than your child (e.g. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT). I do not think that this is an error but you can also have Bugfixes in your parent project. And it's nice for the sake of consistency

Comment: That’ll work on a laptop perhaps but when this sub module is running on an on demand pod in kubernetes then we can’t be running parent and child module builds. Versioning difference doesn’t cause any issues as child modules will change more frequently than parent.

Comment: well OP did not state that he want it to run it on a kubernetes cluster. Of course if you want the module available non-locally you have to deploy it on a proper repo. But here OP just want to build it locally as far as we know.

Comment: It doesn’t mention kubernetes nor does it mention local. That’s not the problem I’m asking for. The problem that local or not if a repository tag is declared, it should be inherited and hence find the parent Pom Pom high it is not doing.